# type '_JsonQuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast"

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have issues to display data from Firebase. Here is the code I used in my FutureBuilder.

This is the error that I got

> "The following _CastError was thrown building FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>#c8a1c):
> type '_JsonQuerySnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast"

**Code**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:errandkaba_app/widgets/custom_action_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ServicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? serviceId;
  const ServicePage({Key? key, this.serviceId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ServicePageState createState() => _ServicePageState();
}

class _ServicePageState extends State<ServicePage> {
  final CollectionReference _servicesRef =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("cleaning");



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          FutureBuilder (
            future: _servicesRef.get(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              //if has error
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text("Error ${snapshot.error}"),
                  ),
                );
              }

              if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
                Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>;

                return ListView(
                  children: [
                    Image.network(
                        "${documentData['images'][0]}"
                    ),
                  ],
                );

              }
```

Comment: what is `snapshot.data` value ?

Comment: the value is the image URL in the firebase Firestore

Answer (score 7):

try `snapshot.data` to `snapshot.data!.data()`

Comment: I already tried it and it gives me this "The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. "

Comment: oh,  i found it,  _servicesRef.get() is return QuerySnapshot, not DocumentSnapshot, so if you want to read it, try snapshot.docs, not snapshot.data.

Comment: I tried puting `FutureBuilder <QuerySnapshot>` and `Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data!.docs as Map<String, dynamic>;` but still got this type 'List<_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Answer (score 4):

Change the `FutureBuilder` to `FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>` (or `StreamBuilder< QuerySnapshot>` for `StreamBuilder`)

Then cast the data this way

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> documentData = snapshot.data?.docs.map((e) => e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?).toList();
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you @vkt

Answer (score 1):

I did this `FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>(future: _servicesRef.doc(widget.serviceId).get()` and used this `Map<String, dynamic> documentData = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userId).get(),
  builder: (ctx,*AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>>>* snapshot){
    return Text(
      snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
        ? 'Loading...'
        : snapshot.data!.data()!['userName'],
      .....
```

Provide the type and then it will work as expected else you will have to cast it to the right type before using `data.data()` prop and fun..

Answer (score 0):

create this functiom

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> convertSnapshotToMap(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot)async {final data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>; return data;}
```

then call the function like this

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = await convertSnapshotToMap(snapshot);
```

dont forget to to change  'snapshot' to your _JsonQuerySnapshot data

Answer (score -2):

make your FurtureBuilder like this FurtureBuilder then snapshot.data.data()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).